# SQL UPDATE to do string replacement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some columns like:

```
Provider            url                                                       id       
Apple               https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bin/APPLE_MAY2011.xls         1
HP                  https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bin/HP_MAY2011.xls            2
```

I changed one of the S3 bins and now need to change the url for all rows to be:

```
Apple               https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybin/APPLE_MAY2011.xls         1
HP                  https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybin/HP_MAY2011.xls            2
```

In other words, I need to change `my-bin` to `mybin`. How would I do this directly in SQL (instead of SELECTING everything and iterating and doing an INSERT for every row?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
update TABLE_NAME set url = replace(url, 'my-bin', 'mybin');
```